# Problem with use of gems (mode devel vs. production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I use rails 3.
In development mode I installed some gems for Testing (diff-lcs, nokogiri, rspec, webrat).
Since I did that, if I try to cap-deploy to the production server, it complains:
"Could not find diff-lcs in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)"

I don't want to install them on the server, because I don't need the testing purpose gems on the production server.
Can I put something in the Gemfile to maybe exclude them for production mode?

Or else how can I handle this?

Thank you very much for answering this questiion by a struggling beginner...

Answer (score 0):

You can put those gems in their own group like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'diff-lcs'
end
```

This page explains groups in more details: http://gembundler.com/groups.html

Comment: thank you for answering!! I did that but I still get the same error. Do I have to somehow tell the app on the server to read in the Gemfile again?

Comment: you might need to explicitly tell capistrano that you don't want the test and development groups by using `set :bundle_without, [:test, :development]`. See here for further details on that: http://blog.josephholsten.com/2010/09/deploying-with-bundler-and-capistrano/